# How to stop the meteor method

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I am using the react and meteor in my application. There are many front-end routes in my application i.e /settings, /dashboard, /reports. The problem is that I'm calling the **one meteor methods** multiple times from routes '/reports' but If I change the route to another i.e '/settings' then the meteor methods still is in execution state in the server side, So it blocks another method (which call from the route /settings).

Can we stop the meteor method queue processing in server-side If component unmount?

Comment: It sounds like your meteor method is taking some time to complete - what is the processing that takes so long? Can this be optimised?

Comment: @Mikkel, No we can't optimize the code.

Comment: Maybe you post the code of the method? In some cases there is optimization possible that you may not notice.

Comment: the way that you have used may be incorrect.share the code

Comment: a little code snippet would be a great help. instead of us thinking theoretically overtime